# How to Pattern Match With Algebraic Types in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

The goal of the assignment I am working on is to create a bunch of different functions that involve searching a data type called a Trie, in which the constructor is defined as

```
data Trie = MakeTrie Char [Trie] deriving Eq
```

I am tying to first build simple functions so I can figure out how to descend this Trie, but it seems like pattern matching is not working.

```
test :: Trie -> Bool
test t
    | t == MakeTrie '.' [_] = True
    | otherwise = False
```

I get an error stating that a hole was found and that relevant bindings include t :: Trie. How can I let the interpreter know that [_] represents a list of Tries? The reason I am doing this is because I have no idea how else do go ahead descending my Trie later if I don't use pattern matching.

Comment: `[_]` represents a list with one element.

Comment: By writing `_` instead of `[_]`, `[_]` means a list of *one* element. But using `==` is already the problem here, you should pattern match, not use `==`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should checkout the [function syntax chapter](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions) in **Learn You A Haskell** (particularly the first section on pattern matching).

This is how you do pattern matching in Haskell for this example:

```
test :: Trie -> Bool
test (MakeTrie '.' _) = True
test _ = False
```

Testing:

```
Prelude> test (MakeTrie '.' [])
True
Prelude> test (MakeTrie 'a' [])
False
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems here:

1. if you write `[_]`, this is a pattern that says "*a list of one element, regardless what that element is*"; and
2. you can not do pattern matching with `(==)`.

Indeed `(==)` is a function that compares two objects. But it is not said that if two objects are equal, that these share the same constructor, etc. `(==)` can implement an arbitrary equivalence relation.

We can write the function as:

```
test :: Trie -> Bool
test (MakeTrie '.' _) = True
test _ = False
```

So here the first clause checks if the input matches the pattern `MakeTrie '.' _`, so it checks if it is the `MakeTrie` data constructor where the first parameter is a `'.'`, the second parameter can by anything.

The second clause matches everything, and returns `False` in that case.